# How to disable the main GPU of a laptop using Manjaro linux GRUB command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, laptop, grub, vga

I have a sony Vaio VPCEB46FA and the ATI GPU got fried because of overload (it doesnt work anymore) so I wanted to disable it and run on the Intel GPU.
I Have Manjaro OS which is an Arch linux based OS and it doesnt allow me to access the GUI so I need to do this on the GRUB command line.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you can disable the discrete GPU in uEFI that would be, by far, the best way. Not having that possibility, doing that from Grub isn't possible and shouldn't be needed anyway: https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Configure_Graphics_Cards#Dual_GPU This means it'll always use the iGPU Intel by default. The desktop not loading is probably related to some other problem.

Comment: @ChanganAuto It definitely is the GPU its giving the same artifacts that it gave on windows and I disabled the main GPU it ran perfectly on the intel....now it seems Prime isnt working properly...so if I cant do it on GRUB cli is there another through I make sure the intel gpu is the choosen one?

Comment: All you should know about graphics in Manjaro is at the link above.